# C#, how I find out derived type from an abstract class? (TextWriter)

Tags: c#, types

I probably did not use the right title but I am not sure about the terms.

So I wanted to use TextWriter which is an abstract class. I found a piece of code that looks like this:

```
TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("path");
```

EDIT: How do I know that StreamWriter type is required? All I can see from the code of TextWriter is that it is abstract.

Comment: I dont understand your question. - `How would I know what to use` ....

Comment: What holds you back from just using `TextWriter`?

Comment: Me neither. Why do you care if the method returns a `StreamQriter` or even a `MyClass`, as long as all those classes are an instance of `TextWrter`?

Comment: But how do I know that StreamWriter is required? That is the point of my question.

Comment: Who/what says streamwriter is "required"

Comment: @Jamiec I guess he meant "returned" instead of "required".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I know that StreamWriter type is required?

Well, `StreamWriter` is *not* required. It can be used, but not *required*.

Declaring a variable with a compile type of `TextWriter` simply means that any kind of `TextWriter` can be assigned to it. You can for example put a `StringWriter` in there:

```
TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder("Hello World!"));
```

There is no problem compiling that.

What matters is not what is required to be put there, but what you want to do. If you want to write to a stream go put a `StreamWriter` in there, if you want to write to a `StringBuilder` go put a `StringWriter` there, if you want to write to something else go create a subclass of your own and use that there.

Also, you don't even need to write `TextWriter`. You can very well do something like this:

```
StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("path");
```

"Then what's the use of `TextWriter` if I can just specify what specific type I want?" you might ask.

Sometimes you might want to write a method that does something in general, right? Like writing "Hello World", but the method does not care where it will write to.

```
public static void WriteHelloWorld(TextWriter writer) {
    writer.Write("Hello World");
}
```

If you pass a `StreamWriter` it will write to a stream. If you pass a `StringWriter` it will write to a string and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that is much closer to what I would like to learn. So - how do you know that StringWriter can be used, for example? This is all I am asking. I cannot see how I can tell that by the code itself.

Comment: @user970696 Everything that inherits from `TextWriter` can be used. It is shown in the docs what types in the .NET framework inherits from it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textwriter(v=vs.110).aspx Look at the "Inheritance Hierarchy" section. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a `StreamWriter`instance returned. From the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext(v=vs.110).aspx) about `File.CreateText Method (String)`:

> This method is equivalent to the StreamWriter(String, Boolean) constructor overload with the append parameter set to false.

But it is indeed recommended to use it as an object of the abstract class.

If you wnat, you can check the type of the returned instance:

```
TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("path");
Type type = writer.GetType(); //System.IO.StreamWriter in this case
```

Comment: @user970696 I added the code to show the type of the `writer` instance

Comment: But that is not what I am asking. How do you know that StreamWriter is expected? How would you know from the code of the TextWriter? I did not know what to use unless I looked at MSDN.